# SQL Server: usage of cursor inevitable here?

Tags: sql-server, split, cursor

I got a table where there is only one column of type `varchar(max)`, looks somehow like this:

```
COLUMN_A
jon;jonny;johana
jon
fred;brian
james;lars;cliff;kirk
```

Now I want to split those names and have a row for each name, like:

```
COLUMN_A
jon
jonny
johana
jon
fred
brian
james
lars
cliff
kirk
```

...at the moment I call my split function with a cursor. Do you think there is a better and more performant solution for that?

Comment: Yes. There are about a dozen. Have you tried searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In T-SQL:

```
Begin Transaction
While Exists (Select * From Table 
              where CharIndex(';', column_A) > 0)
    Begin
       Insert Table(column_A)
       Select Left(column_A, charIndex(';', column_A)-1)
       Where charIndex(';', column_A) > 0
       -- next 3 lines only if you want to avoid duplicates
       And Not exists (Select * From table 
                       Where column_A = Left(column_A, 
                         charIndex(';', column_A)-1))
       Update Table set column_A
          = substring(columnA, 1+charIndex(';', column_A), 
                    len(column_A) - charIndex(';', column_A))
       From table
       Where charIndex(';', column_A) > 0
    End
Commit Transaction
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Charles. first tests came up with a faster performance by the cursor approach. I thought, the cursor is usually a quite slow alternative...nevertheless thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use XML:

```
DECLARE @xml xml;
WITH cte AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
('jon;jonny;johana'),
('jon'),
('fred;brian'),
('james;lars;cliff;kirk')) as t(COLUMN_A)
)

SELECT @xml = (
SELECT cast('<e>' + REPLACE(COLUMN_A,';','</e><e>') + '</e>' as xml)
FROM cte
FOR XML PATH(''))


SELECT n.v.value('.','nvarchar(50)') as COLUMN_A
FROM @xml.nodes('/e') AS n(v);
```

Result:

```
COLUMN_A
-----------
jon
jonny
johana
jon
fred
brian
james
lars
cliff
kirk

(10 row(s) affected)
```